# File upload error. Cannot upload .key (keynote) files

Tags: assets, upload

I am trying allow users to upload keynote and powerpoint files. Powerpoint works fine. Keynote fails. I do not have any asset type restrictions in place. Why am I unable to upload asset type .key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like .key files are not included in the [default allowed file extensions](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php#L48). But you can manually add it with the [`extraAllowedFileExtensions`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#extraAllowedFileExtensions) setting in your config/general.php file:

```php
'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'key'
```

Comment: No problem @carlcs... Your answer was so close, I didn't feel it was necessary to post a competing answer. :)